# Show that $T$ is continuous

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have a question about how to response to:

> Given a Banach space X and $T: X \rightarrow X^{*}$ a linear operator such that $\langle Tx,x\rangle \geq 0$ for all $x \in X$. Show that $T$ is continuous.

I know that this operator sends points in linear continuous functionals, I think that it is a positive form but, I actually don't know how to start my proof.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Nice one. I've been playing with inequalities to use Banach-Steinhaus theorem for a while, but no luck so far.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being silly here, but where/how does an inner product enter the picture?

Comment: @tci: $\langle Tx,x\rangle$ is fairly common notation for evaluating the functional $Tx$ on the vector $x$.

Comment: But if we have an inner product could it be that $X$ is actually a Hilbert space?

Comment: @MattN We don't have an inner product. Inner product is a special case of dual pairing - nondegenerate, positive definite bilinear form defined on product of arbitrary two spaces. It's usually denoted by brackets. Important special case of dual pairing is evaluation of functional - for $x\in X$, $\lambda\in X^*$ we define $\langle \lambda, x\rangle$ as $\lambda(x)$. That's what this notation stands for in this question.

Comment: @MarcinŁoś Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Found by related questions panel: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/476403/117513. Banach-Steinhaus indeed, just more sheer cleverness than I had :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can do it using the Closed Graph Theorem, as follows.

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $X$ such that $x_n\to 0$ and $Tx_n$ has a limit $\phi\in X^*$. We have to show that $\phi=0$.

Observe first that for any $x\in X$ and all $n\in\mathbb N$, we have 
$$\langle T(x_n+x),x_n+x\rangle\geq 0\, . $$

Now, expand the "product" (using the linearity of $T$): this gives
$$\langle T(x_n+x),x_n+x\rangle =\langle Tx_n,x_n\rangle+\langle Tx_n, x\rangle +\langle Tx,x_n\rangle+\langle Tx,x\rangle \, .$$

By assumption on the sequence $(x_n)$, it follows that 
$$ \langle T(x_n+x),x_n+x\rangle\to \langle \phi,x\rangle+\langle Tx, x\rangle\, .$$
So we have 
$$\forall x\in X\;:\; \langle \phi,x\rangle\geq -\langle Tx,x\rangle\, .$$

Replacing $x$ by $-x$ and since $\langle T(-x),-x\rangle =\langle Tx,x\rangle$, we also get $-\langle \phi,x\rangle\geq -\langle Tx,x\rangle$, i.e. $\langle \phi,x\rangle\leq \langle Tx,x\rangle$. Hence:
$$\forall x\in X\;:\; \vert\langle \phi,x\rangle\vert\leq \langle Tx,x\rangle\, . $$

Now, replace $x$ by $tx$, $t>0$: since $\langle T(tx),tx\rangle=t^2\langle Tx,x\rangle$, this gives
$$\vert \langle \phi,x\rangle\vert\leq t\,\langle Tx,x\rangle\, .$$
Letting $t\to 0^+$, it follows that $\langle \phi,x\rangle=0$ for all $x\in X$, as required.

Comment: +1, great answer.  Took me a bit to justify that $\langle T(x_n + x), x_n + x \rangle \to \langle \phi, x \rangle + \langle Tx, x \rangle$ from the assumptions.

Comment: @Goos Thanks for the comment.